# filtering variant list according to target regions

Tags: genomics

I have a variant list in VCF file for a particular disease, I want to filter these variants according to exonic regions in a BED file using a Perl script. How I do this?

Comment: Sounds more like a question for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about Biology.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel.  Use BEDTools.

And no one on any Stack Exchange board wants to write you a perl script.

Answer (score 0):

As a fuller explanation, use [bedtools](http://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html) with the intersect command:

```
bedtools intersect -u -a variantList.vcf -b exonicRegions.bed > filteredVariants.vcf
```

While this should work, if your vcf version is giving you trouble use [vcf2bed](http://bedops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/reference/file-management/conversion/vcf2bed.html) to convert the vcf to a bed file, then intersect directly.